# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to JavaEE and i have been working on a simlpe Springboot project.
Each time i run it i get this error:

Please feel free to answer to my question and any improvemnet in the code is Highly Appreciate.

```
Field sessionFactory in com.example.dao.CartDaoImpl required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to get Session from EntityManager which is already configured in `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. So inject EntityManager instead of SessionFactory:

```
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private Session getSession() {
        return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    }
```

And use getSession() method where you need.

Answer (score 1):

1. you need :

   - Add the SessionFactory bean in the Application class.
   - Add the Current Session Context class in application.properties.
   - Use the SessionFactory using @Autowired annotation.
   - add into application.properties

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext`

and add this

```
spring.datasource.url=......
spring.datasource.username=....
spring.datasource.password=.....
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=.......
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

2. you use @Transactional , but you didn't configured it.You should also configure it. add @EnableTransactionManagement into config class and config this bean.

here is good example for configuration [A Guide to Hibernate with Spring 4](http://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa)

---

Just remarks : 
1# you use in UserServiceImpl for example

```
@Component
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {...
  ....
}
```

use only @Component or @Service but not both as it's redundant. Service is alread a Component.

2# in methods where you have only read operation us instead of default `@Transactional` this `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`

3#
in methods like `void addCustomerOrder(CustomerOrder customerOrder);` better return boolean or some object like CustomerOrder  than return just void.

4# class Queries is not Serializable

5# better use lazy as default value than fetch = FetchType.EAGER

6# dao class CartDaoImpl has dependency on service class , it's strange.

7# in some cases you have transaction on dao level in another on service

8# if you can create sub package impl and move all implementation into one.

you will have com.dao with N interfaces and com.dao.impl with N implementations for them , and not one package com.dao with N+N intercases and classes

---

add this into pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and create package configs `com.configs` and configure like  [DatabaseConfig](https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/blob/master/spring-boot-mysql-hibernate/src/main/java/netgloo/configs/DatabaseConfig.java)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am so lost with the configuration part(the first part you mention). It would nice if you could update your answer with the files after your suggestions. I tried my self but i get more errors :(

Comment: see my updates . and if you have any exception show it

Answer (score 0):

i see you project and i found that there is no `SessionFactory` class or configuration for `SessionFactory` into your project and you are use `@Autowired` for `SessionFactory` in `CartDaoImpl` clas. that is the main issue. you need to configure the `SessionFactory`

yo can refer bellow example :
http://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hibernate-5-example

Comment: you can configure it by java code or you can also configure using `xml` and `.property`  file. its all up to you. if you want to go with BeanConfig.java, you can configure it. i suggest you use xml configuration

Comment: I tried and i couldnot get the error fixed,since you downloaded the projectand you managed to fixed the error could you upload it for me ?

Comment: refer this project and try to configure it: https://github.com/mdeinum/samples/blob/master/spring-boot-plain-hibernate/src/main/java/biz/deinum/sample/hibernate/Application.java
 or  you can also refer this link 
https://blog.pranavek.com/using-hibernate-sessionfactory-in-spring-boot-app/

Answer (score 0):

Create service and use it to get session from EntityManager:

```
@Service
public class HibernateService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public <R> NativeQuery<R> createNativeQuery(String sqlString, Class<R> resultClass) {
        return getSession().createNativeQuery(sqlString, resultClass);
    }

    public NativeQuery createNativeQuery(String sqlString) {
        return getSession().createNativeQuery(sqlString);
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    }
}
```

you can add more methods to reduce amount of written code.

Answer (score 0):

Using Hibernate 5 simple check the below

-- Check the base package is scan (HibernateConfig.java)

-- Check the valid annotation in file
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement

-- check the all valid beans are created or not
LocalSessionFactoryBean,HibernateTransactionManager,HibernateTemplate