# Parameter 0 of constructor in ServiceImpl required a bean of type DAO that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

While creating a service that will save the object in the DB using Hibernate as ORM, I'm unable to start the application.

I'm using Spring Boot and Hibernate. My ServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class PropertyServiceImpl implements PropertyService{

private PropertyDAO propertyDAO;

    public PropertyServiceImpl(){
    System.out.println("inside propertyserviceimpl constructor");
}

@Autowired
public PropertyServiceImpl(PropertyDAO propertyDAO){
    this.propertyDAO = propertyDAO;
    System.out.println("inside save");
}

@Transactional
public void save(Property property) {
    propertyDAO.save(property);
}

@Override
public List findAll() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

PropertyDAO.java

```
public interface PropertyDAO {

public void save(Property property);

 }
```

PropertyDAOImpl implement the DAO

```
public class PropertyDAOImpl implements PropertyDAO{

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void save(Property property) {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(property);
}
```

}

I'm getting the following error message when I start the SpringBoot Application.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.flarow.flarowhomes.services.PropertyServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.flarow.flarowhomes.dao.PropertyDAO' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.flarow.flarowhomes.dao.PropertyDAO' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Show `PropertyDAO` class which isn't found

Comment: updated the question with PropertyDAO

Comment: But where is the concrete class that is marked as a Spring bean and implements that PropertyDAO interface?

Comment: PropertyDAOImpl implements PropertyDAO

Comment: But is it a **Spring bean**? Does it has a Component annotation (or a Service annotation, or a Repository annotation), that marks it as a Spring bean? Spring only injects Sring beans. Not random classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [@Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html) to your DAO implementation class so it will be found:

```
@Repository
public class PropertyDAOImpl implements PropertyDAO {
```

> Teams implementing traditional Java EE patterns such as "Data Access Object" may also apply this stereotype to DAO classes, though care should be taken to understand the distinction between Data Access Object and DDD-style repositories before doing so.

Comment: this helps me to get rid of the error I was facing. But introduces a new error

`Description:

Field sessionFactory in com.flarow.flarowhomes.dao.PropertyDAOImpl required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' in your configuration.`

Comment: @AnamikAdhikary see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120775/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-org-hibernate-sessionfactory-in-your-configur or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50300758/spring-boot-a-bean-of-type-org-hibernate-sessionfactory-that-could-not-be-fou

Answer (score 0):

Change your PropertyDAO as follows:

```
public interface PropertyDAO extends JpaRepository<Property, Integer>{ }
```

Comment: it would require me to change the return type of my save method from void.

Comment: Yeah, you would return your Property that you saved.